# Mysql:selects all rows with a starting date value from within the last 30 days

Tags: mysql

Columns in my table

1)id

2) name

3) starting_time.

The date is stored in `starting_time` field as a normal string and the format is `dd-mm-yyyy`

I am trying to get records in which the `starting_time` is not more than 30 days from the current date.

Here is the query I have tried so far

```
SELECT *  FROM `agency_courses` 
        WHERE  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= STR_TO_DATE(agency_courses.starting_time, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

But it returns even if the starting_time more than 30 days from the current date.

**UPDATE**

I just tried this but returns 0 rows

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `agency_courses` 
        WHERE   STR_TO_DATE(agency_courses.starting_time, '%d-%m-%Y') <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
id name starting_time
1  test1 26-04-2019
2  test2 02-03-2019
3  test3 08-03-2019
```

Expected result

```
    2  test2 02-03-2019
    3  test3 08-03-2019
```

Comment: add  a data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge updated the sample data

Comment: i have posted  some suggestion in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using

```
select COUNT(*) 
FROM `agency_courses` 
WHERE str_to_date(agency_courses.starting_time, '%d-%m-%Y')
        BETWEEN NOW() 
         AND DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('26-04-2019', '%d-%m-%Y'), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

but 
Looking to your sample seems you want the value between now() and now()  + 30 day

```
select COUNT(*) 
FROM `agency_courses` 
WHERE str_to_date(agency_courses.starting_time , '%d-%m-%Y')
    BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: Returns  0 rows  do i need to convert `starting_time` to date ??

Answer (score 0):

The Compare is wrong. You want only see rows where OLDER than currdate - interval 30 Day. So change your query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `agency_courses` 
        WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(agency_courses.starting_time, '%d-%m-%Y') >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: add sample date and the create table

Comment: added the sample data